# Is there a type similar to a struct with no members in the C++ standard library?

Tags: c++

Sometimes it is necessary to pass a dummy value without any data to some template. For example:

```
template <typename X, typename Y> 
struct BoundaryConditions {
  X x; Y y;
  BoundaryConditions(typename X::init xi, typename Y::init yi) : x(xi), y(yi) {
    ...
  }
};
```

We may wish to implement free boundary conditions that doesn't take any parameters. It's pretty easy to implement such a thing with type checking:

```
struct Nothing {};
Nothing nothing = Nothing();

struct Free {
  typedef Nothing init;
  ...
};

BoundaryConditions<Free, Fixed> foo(nothing, 100);
```

So the matter of my question: is there an implementation of something like my `Nothing` type in the standard library or boost?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use empty [tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple). Like `std::tuple<>();`

Comment: @ziggystar, you comment under the question starts with _You are looking for a unit type_, and the comment here with _The empty tuple is the unit type_; by transitivity this implies _You are looking for the empty tuple_, which is what this answer gives. Why shouldn't it be accepted?

Answer (score 5):

How about `boost::none` and `boost::none_t`?

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/boost/none.hpp

Comment: Probably the best match but the tuple solution requires only std.

Answer (score 4):

The usual solution is to use `void`, but this requires partial specialization of the template (which is also usual, since otherwise, it requires more space).

Comment: Also besides requiring more space this does not work at all if there is a function returning `T&` since `void &` can't be returned. I think it does not really matter which type is used, an empty `struct None {};` does the trick already as it will be zero size.

Answer (score 2):

`void` seems like a natural way, since it is > void <.
However C++ won't allow instantiating this type hence it is useless when having to declaring numerous template classes.
The typical use of a separate type that allows that but denotes an 'empty type' would be a template event bus specialized for 'no data' provided in each event.
Such as:

```
#include <variant>
typedef std::monostate nothing;
...
observable<nothing> bus;
```

This is as portable as any other type, but is embedded in `std` so there's some level of standardization.

Answer (score 0):

[Boost.MPL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/mpl/doc/index.html) offers the type [`void_`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/void.html).